# Should I flag a question after I've messed up my close vote?

Tags: support, closing

I voted to close **[this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303066/cant-remember-a-name-of-a-mini-car-shooting-game)** question but since it's really early in the morning (and I haven't had my coffee yet!) I messed up my close vote and VTC'd as "Developer intent" which I retracted immediately.

Obviously this question has nothing to do with Developer intent, but still has to be closed since it's an ITG question without an artifact of the game.

What can I do in a situation like this? I wanted to flag it for mod-attention but that might be a bit overkill. The only thing I did now was leaving a comment.

Comment: imo just leave the close vote with the wrong reason, when it's closed, I'm fairly sure the majority reason will be displayed so it should be fine. Might be a little worse if you were the first person to vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I flag a question after I messed up my close vote?

No, your best bet is to leave a comment explaining the correct close reason, or link the question in chat.

As you know, after retracting a close vote you are unable to re-vote to close for a different reason. Note that the question will still be in the Close Vote review queue, so there will still be eyeballs on the question at hand. There are plenty of regular users around with the power to close vote as well, so if they see the same problem you do, there will be plenty of other voters the help out.

Your best option in future would be not to retract, and to leave a comment for future close voters as to what you meant for your close vote reason to be.

You could also link the question in chat and explain the situation there as well, I'm sure the community members will be happy to help.